# Can I use "since when" to ask about a future?

Tags: grammar, questions

I am thinking what is the best expression for the following: I know that a directive will be effective sometime in the next week. So I would ask: "Since when is the directive effective?" Which I believe is not correct.
I assume that **since when** can only refer to the past, but not sure about that. Also the phrase "as of", what a question with that would look like? "As of when"?

Comment: “As of when will the directive be effective?” is _grammatical_, but not likely to ever be uttered by any native speaker. It’s more natural, when speaking of directives futuristically being effective, to ask when they _come into effect_ or _take effect_ or _become effective_ or something along those lines.

Comment: '_From when_ is the directive effective ?' is the idiomatic way to query an event which may be in the past, present or future.